# How to disable a drop down list item in dropdown list on load using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select, disabled-control

I have dropdown list with some list items . Here ,  i need to disable a single item in the dropdown list .

I mean value should be present in dropdown list but should not be selectable.

I have tried in the following way with no luck:

```
 $("#SelectorList select option [value*='n/a']").prop('disabled',true);
```

But, it is not working.i was able to disable entire dropdown list by using

```
 $("#SelectorList").prop('disabled',true);
```

What is the change that i need to do inorder to make this work. please help.

Comment: have your tried `attr` method instead `prop`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `SelectorList` is id of `select` you can use combination of desandant selector and attribute value selector with contains wild card.

```
$("#SelectorList option[value*='n/a']").prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: @Adil..Thanks ..its working fine..Any idea how to do it, if it is inside Jqgrid..

Comment: I think it will work as you are using id for select. If you have multiple selects in grid then you can use class selector or assign ids in some pattern and make selector accordingly

Comment: You can put it in document.ready or after that, when SelectorList is present in DOM

Answer (score 3):

Typo remove space

```
$("#SelectorList option[value*='n/a']").prop('disabled',true);
                       ^ //remove space here
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xp5p5/)</kbd>